# Prevent apache from automatically change mime type

Tags: php, apache, mime-types

I generate a Wave-File with PHP. The data is read from a wav file on the server, manipulated and finally sent to the user.

The problem now: Apache delivers this file as Content-Type: application/x-wave. Even though I use header('Content-Type: audio/wave') and the script has extension .php.

At a first glance, Apache has no way to know that I'm sending a wav-file. So I guess it detects the mime type automatically from the content being sent. Is there a way to stop this behavior and force Apache to use the mime type which is specified by header(...)?

The reason why this mime type issue leads to a problem is: Firefox does not accept application/x-wave, but It accepts audio/wave.

Comment: Try adding a "new" mime type in .htaccess with this: AddType audio/wave wav

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does not help. I wonder whether it could be not the server but a firewall in the company network which changes the mime type according to the actual content to avoid files being smuggled with misleading mime types.

Comment: Are you setting the file extension in you php script? If not, try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there is mod_mime_magic installed on the server. This mod will automatically set the mime type automatically according to the data stream leaving the server. So I can do whatever I want, the file will always leave the server as application/x-wave.

Since I do not have access to mod_mime_magic configuration, I'm currently checking with my provider what they can do.